# Struct inherits codable and a protocol that has a property that is a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, opaque-types

I have a service that returns read-only data. In the service, I am modifying and saving the data and I have properties I want to hide outside the service. I want to expose only protocols in the interface of my service so that other developers can not create or modify these objects by mistake.

This is what it looks like

```
class MyService {
  func getData() -> [Protocol1]
}

protocol Protocol1 {
  var protocol2: Protocol2 { get }
}

protocol Protocol2 { }

struct Struct1: Protocol1, Codable {
  var id: String
  var lastModified: Date
  var protocol2: Struct2 // Error: Type 'Struct1' does not conform to protocol 'Protocol1'
}

struct Struct2: Protocol2, Codable { }
```

Am I out of luck? Am I going to need to just create a struct that is used outside the service and a struct for inside the service?

Comment: If you don't want to create them by mistake, make their `init` private. There's no need for a protocol. If you want to make their properties unmodifiable, mark them `private(set)`. Then they're readable from the outside, but only writable from the type. Protocols aren't for access control. You can always just `as Struct1` to remove the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

To make your structure `Struct1` comply to `Protocol1`, you can make `protocol2` a computed property:

```
struct Struct1: Protocol1, Codable {
  var id: String
  var lastModified: Date
  var protocol2: Protocol2  { get { struct2 } }
  private var struct2: Struct2 
}
```